# how to send email in laravel 5.4 on live server Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send email from laravel 5.4 application and using smtp.gmail.com host, its working fine on localhost but not on live server. how to send email from laravel application without using mailtrap, by using smtp.gmail.com. may I know what changes I have to do in .env and mail.php file? Please check the code of my .env and mail.php file and also find the screenshot of error I am getting

[image]

Comment: Copy pasted error trace is always preferred than an image.

Comment: please never share URL of the images instead upload an image directly in your post.

Comment: Check your error logs to see if google bounces your mails due to a missing dns a-record for your `From` header.

Comment: yes I have tried but no luck

Comment: I have created app password and  env file details are given below                         MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=586
MAIL_USERNAME=myaccount@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=my app password

Comment: I have tried all options and also changed port but no luck

Comment: when I am using mail  as MAIL_DRIVER then its sends mail but not recieved

Comment: Please help me if anyone have solution

Answer (score 1):

Make your *`.env`* file to something like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

For **app password** Read Under the Section [How to generate an App password:](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

After change of *`.env`* must be clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Hello @pradnyaahire Open the above [link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1), Click on Enable. And save it.

Then try to send email again

Comment: Actually, I have used default auth in my application and i am trying to send reset password link.
On Localhost its working fine but on live server its not working giving Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]....
my .env file details are given below
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: @pradnyaahire Change and try this: `'MAIL_ENCRYPTION' => ssl, 'MAIL_PORT' => 465,` After completion of .env edit, must be clear cache

Comment: changed port and  MAIL_ENCRYPTION also but getting same error

Comment: @pradnyaahire  replaced ` 'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),` with `'driver' => 'sendmail',` in **config/mail.php**

Comment: Only need to change MAIL_DRIVER? remaining thing is as it is?
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

Comment: I have changed MAIL_DRIVER smtp to sendmail. my mail is sending and giving message "We have e-mailed your password reset link!" but not receiving mail.

Comment: Can you share the details need to do in .env file and mail.php file to send mail on live server?

Comment: with your updated answer mail is sending but not reciving

Comment: @pradnyaahire Are you still facing the problem?

Comment: Yes, still I am facing problem

Comment: @pradnyaahire please configuration like this in your gmail setting Setting > Forwarding and POP/IMAP > POP Download: **Enable POP for all mail** IMAP Access: **Enable IMAP** Allow less secure apps: **ON**

Comment: Hello @Udhav Sarvaiya I have made all changes as per you shown in your command. but by using sendmail its sending mail but not reciving  and by using smtp its giving above error

Comment: I am really frustrate

Comment: @pradnyaahire Please try on a different Google Account, or check the code in other projects to know whether the code is wrong.